# Get name of property with Reflection/StackTrace (or whatever)?

Tags: c#, reflection, stack-trace, system.reflection, debug-backtrace

i.e. If you use this, it can trigger `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`:

```
try 
{
  Dictionary<int,int> ZZZ; 
  ZZZ[1]= ..;
}
catch(Exception e)
{    
    var stackTrace = new StackTrace(e);
    var frames = stackTrace.GetFrames();
    var method = frames[0].GetMethod(); 
    Console.WriteLine(method.Name);
}
```

However with StackTrace we can get the name of method, where this error happens.

But, how we can get the name of property which triggered error? In other languages like `php`, there is way to find (using `debug_backtrace`) the method which happened last time.

Is there anything similar, so it can find that last time was called i.e. `set_ZZZ()` (autosetter) method, or if it can directly say that `ZZZ` property caused issue?

Comment: You only can get the line of code whose  responsible for error only in Debug mode not in release mode.

Comment: @nAviD ok, and in debug mode, how to see line number ? tried `.GetILOffset()` etc, but none of them catches correctly. WHy cant reflection detect that last method happened was `set_ZZZ()` ?

Comment: You might be interested in this documentation page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Try `new StackTrace(e, true)` to get the line number. Based on that code sample, reflection can't tell you that the last method was `set_ZZZ` because no such method is ever called. There is no `ZZZ` property, just a variable local to the `try` block.

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson is that was private variable (instead of local), then wouldnt it trigger autosetter (`set_ZZZ`) method?

Comment: @T.Todua I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. If you're asking if `ZZZ` were actually a property on some class, and you tried to set it on a `null` instance of that class then `set_ZZZ` would not be in the stack trace. `set_ZZZ` cannot be called on a `null`, so execution will never enter the generated set method.